# Django. Annotate wtih Count parameter doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```py
class Parameter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)


class ProductParameter(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Продукт', related_name='parameters')
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(
        'Parameter',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Параметр',
        related_name='product_parameters'
    )
```

I do the queryset for getting all parameters that has more than 1 ProductParameter:

```py
parameters = Parameter.objects.annotate(
    count=Count('product_parameters')
).exclude(count__lte=1)
```

But that's not working. When a parameter obj has 2 ProductParameter objects, the count equals to 1.
When I use the expression below, all works:

```py
parameters = [param for param in Parameter.objects.all() if param.product_parameters.count() > 1]
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using count as the field name is the issue. Try renaming it or omitting it to use the defaulted field name.

```
parameters = Parameter.objects.annotate(Count('product_parameters')
).exclude(product_parameters__count__lte=1)
```